# How to prosecute plagiarism when the discoverer of the plagiarism is an outside third party?

Tags: phd, plagiarism, legal-issues

Recently a group of students have investigated the the alleged plagiarism in the thesis of one of the most famous alumnus's of Glasgow Caledonian University. In one specific case, a crowd-sourced project highlights very convincing evidence of plagiarism throughout the process. Is there any global authority to investigate this type of issue and put it through required legal steps?

Comment: Usually, the alma mater of the alumni in question should be contacted. They will start an investigation, if the claim is justified (there are some proofs etc.).

Comment: the GCU is contacted last week and also several years ago but as i mentioned they are reluctant because of political issues, they even did not made the thesis publicly available for years, that's why we are seeking and external tool to put them under pressure.

Comment: (Pet peeve: the singular of alumni is [alumnus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alumnus) (also alumna, alumnum), not alumni. Or you can also say "former student".)

Comment: The main faulty assumption in this question is that plagiarism and reception of a PhD isn't actually a legal issue at all (in most countries). E.g., in the U.S. there are no laws addressing those issues. It's purely at the independent discretion of the university.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins The US and its states do have laws against fraud, misappropriation of intellectual property, and copyright violation. I expect the UK and Scotland do too.

Comment: Contact journalists you expect to be sympathetic to your cause or interested in the plagiarists and hope they write articles about it. That should increase pressure on the university to revoke the degree.

Comment: @BasilBourque But none of those things have much of anything to do with plagiarism. Plagiarism is a form of academic dishonesty.

Comment: @BasilBourque and you can't enforce someone else's copyright without their permission, which is certainly a good thing, given the possibility for abuse otherwise. I suspect that the same would apply to intellectual property as well, since this would be on the civil rather than criminal side.

Comment: @origimbo it does however often get more complicated than that as there exist publishers who demand written consent for transfer of all exclusive rights prior to submission effective upon acceptance of an article. In those cases the publisher can try and enforce if the scientific authors do not care personally or even if they would oppose doing so.

Comment: You do understand most (all?) papers register decent levels of plagiarism, even when not plagiarized at all. Things like TurnItIn.com regularly register an original piece at 10-20% plagiarized, even worse when the writer quotes other works legitimately. So much so, that most professors will give an upper limit threshold, under-which they ignore. The point is... before you gallivant off and try to take down the president of a foreign nation for plagiarism (which is unlikely at all), perhaps you should be more certain than just running the piece through some software or "crowd sourced" process..

Comment: I have removed all identifying information as it is both irrelevant to the question at hand and politically unnecessary. Please do not edit it back in; engaging in edit wars will result in the question being locked.

Answer (score 35):

There is no single global authority that deals with academic plagiarism.

While the current legal system stands, there's no quick and reliable way to prosecute anyone because everyone has a right to defend in court, and court processes are long, tedious and don't always result in a way that you expect. Your question seems to assume that plagiarism should lead to immediate dismissal of the president; this will not happen. Actually, this should not happen without a thorough investigation.

This being said, I sympathise with your cause, but you have little legal ground here. The university has the right to revoke his PhD degree, should the university decide so. If the university does not, it's the reputation of the university that is at stake. You have the right to distribute this information and show that the university officials are caring about politics more than about science.

Also, it is highly unlikely that a plagiarised PhD thesis would get a president of any country to quit. I have been closely following the work of [Dissernet](https://www.dissernet.org/), a similar group in Russia that examines PhD theses for plagiarism. While they have uncovered plagiarism in theses of several high-ranked officials, including the Minister for Culture, no one in Russia bothered to admit it, much less quit, [zu Guttenberg style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttenberg_plagiarism_scandal).

Comment: and as per Guttenberg, trial by gutter press is probably the way forward. If the university sees potentially significant damage to its reputation as a result of not taking action they will probably take action.